# Docker commit - does not keep new settings?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create (*without* a dockerfile) a custom image (`apache`) which I want to publish to other programmers.

I already have this image :

```
> docker images 

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
eboraas/apache      latest              ddf3c3b74564        3 months ago        365MB
```

Now let's create a container with settings :

```
docker run -p 8520:80 -v //c/Users/sff/apache:/var/www/html -d eboraas/apache
```

OK , now all is working and I do see the test page :

[image]

BTW -  `docker ps -a` is now :

```
C:\r>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
3a1083fded97        eboraas/apache      "/usr/sbin/apache2ct…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8520->80/tcp   eloquent_heisenberg
```

OK

I was told that I can use `docker commit` in order to keep the **container** as a custom new **image**.

And so I did :

```
C:\r>docker commit 3a1083fded97 131313222/shared-apache
sha256:14135d48fcf827527d655225908a29b15223317810be9cf22651ae375a87a774
```

And it did save new image :

```
C:\r>docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
131313222/shared-apache   latest              14135d48fcf8        49 seconds ago      365MB
eboraas/apache            latest              ddf3c3b74564        3 months ago        365MB
```

But now I expect that  running `docker run 131313222/shared-apache`  -  will *keep(!!)* the folder mapping and the port mapping :

But  If I run this :

```
docker run 131313222/shared-apache
```

I get :

> C:\r>docker run 131313222/shared-apache AH00558: apache2: Could not
>   reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using
>   172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

And obviously the test page doesn't work.

**Question:**

Why doesn't the commit command ( into a new image) save the port and volume mapping ?

In other words : (without a docker file) - how can I create an image that will include its current settings ?  I want developers to start working immediately  as if each was writing :

```
docker run -p 8520:80 -v //c/Users/sff/apache:/var/www/html -d eboraas/apache
```

Shouldn't the commit do that already ?

I want everyone to see what I see without doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Docker image *only* contains its filesystem and a small amount of metadata like the default command to run and environment variable settings.  It doesn't contain any of the other settings you might specify, like port mappings, volume mounts, access to host devices, privileged access to host-level settings, or background mode.  You simply can't create an image that defaults to the settings you show in the question.

If your audience is other programmers, I'd suggest writing up the sequence to build the image as a Dockerfile, and adding that Dockerfile and a shell script or Docker Compose YAML file that runs the image to a common source control repository.

In fact, I'd advise you to never use `docker commit`.  The Dockerfile system is fairly straightforward (if you *could* specify these settings they'd be one line each in the Dockerfile; `ENV foo bar` replaces `docker run -e foo=bar` for example) and Dockerfiles can be checked into source control quite easily.  When you need to rebuild your image – because a new version of Apache is out with a critical security update, because some of the software you bundled changed – a Dockerfile both gives you a record of what exactly you did to build the image, and a single command to actually do it.

Comment: So when i commit, which changes it is committing?

Comment: Any files that have changed in the container since it was started, that aren't in a volume.

Comment: So if I run  interactive terminal and touch a new file , will it be included in the commit?

Comment: Yes...but this really isn't a best practice.